# Inline many x3d files

Tags: inline, x3d, x3dom

I am trying to load many x3d files in a single HTML file using Inline. Some of the scenes load normally but others hang on Loading. It seems there is a limit in the total number of scenes that could be rendered in a single HTML file.

Is this true? Is there any solution to this problem? I want to display as much scenes as needed.

Here is the [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hc4d895xbfbqotp/AAA8a6o1tleiHVa1oPhFpThVa?dl=0) to the example folder where I am calling "Deer.x3d" files several times inside the HTML file.

This example was viewed using Firefox. Using Interned Explorer or Chrome might not work since they don't allow loading local files.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your page also in [x_ite](http://create3000.de/x_ite) which gives better error messages in console. Browsers has limitation in creating WebGL objects like framebuffers. If you create 100 X3D browser within a html page 100 frambuffers or other objects must be created, which are not supported by all browsers.

A better solution is to create preview images of your x3d scenes and on click, or what ever you prefer, open a X3D browser.